# Combining lists in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a signature

```
combine
  :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

function `Combine` takes list built from list,(1 list may be infinity, like repeat 1), and returns list
with the longest list(s) without changing their order.

```
combine [] = []    
combine [[]] = [[]]    
combine [[], [1]] = [[1]]    
combine [[1], [2]] = [[1],[2]]    
combine [[], repeat 1, []] = [repeat 1] value
```

Any ideas?
Thank you
Code:
combine :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
combine [] = []

combine ((xs),[]) = [xs] doesnt work for some reason

Comment: please revise your question to be clearer; you can use the "code" button in formatting (anything indented 4 spaces will be displayed as a block) by editing your post

Comment: 1) Homework questions need a "homework" tag. 2) All questions should include your attempts and ideas so we can help you along, not do the work for you. 3) I can't understand what your want `combine` to do from your text.  4) Please format your code using the "code block" formatting option provided by Stackoverflow.

Comment: "And somehow I must def combine, that it would take list of the lists x and we in the presumption that the x is final and only 1 list may be infinity, it would give back list x with the longest lists without changeing their order" - you should also clarify what you are trying to do, why are trying to do it, and what attempts you have so far

Comment: I, for one, understand what inTrouble is trying to do.

Comment: @erisco you seem to have seen the much clearer, edited version.  Notice the edit was made two hours before your comment and answer.  Stackoverflow questions improve over time, thank goodness (mine included).

Comment: I understood the idea from the code example and the wording did not change all that much -- just saying.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to solve this with a recursive function.

Consider a recursive algorithm that builds an accumulator -- ask for clarification if you are not familiar with the concept of an accumulator. This accumulator will have type `[[a]]`, which is the same as our function's return type. As we iterate over the list of lists using a recursive function, we cons lists onto the accumulator if they are the same length as other lists in the accumulator, or ignore them if they are of less length. However, if the list is of greater length, we scrap everything else in the accumulator and only keep the new, longer list.

This vaguely describes a linear algorithm you may use to solve this problem. Please ask questions in the comments if you wish for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a compare function, e.g.:

```
cmp [] [] = EQ
cmp [] _ = LT
cmp _ [] = GT  
cmp (x:xs) (y:ys) = cmp xs ys
```

Then you can use a helper function that has an accumulator for the current "maximums":

```
combine :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
combine [] = []
combine (x:xs) = comb xs [x] where
   comb [] acc = acc
   comb (x:xs) (y:ys) = case x `cmp` y of
                          EQ -> ???
                          LT -> ???
                          GT -> ???
```

I think you can figure out what to do in the different cases...